# Update multiple view with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple models but one controller. My controller handles the update to one view. In that view I'm displaying three sections with calculations Games Played, Standings, and the Game rusults. I make only one call to post the result of the games and I get everything to update correctly in the database but the only view that updates on post is the game results. I'm forced to use window.location.reload() to get everything to refresh and it does not seem to be the correct approach. I've marked the call to with ////////// CALL TO REFRESH ///////// window.location.reload()

Any help is greatly appreciated.

My controller

```
(function(){
  angular.module('Dashboard',['Games'])
    .controller('dashboardController', ['$http', 'GameService','TournamentService', 'Stats', 'ProgressGrid', function($http,  GameService, TournamentService,Stats, ProgressGrid) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.isEditing = false;
      vm.newGame = {
        awayTeam: '',
        homeTeam: '',
        homeTeamScore: 0,
        awayTeamScore: 0
      };
      vm.showModal = function() {
        vm.isEditing = true;
      }
      vm.hideModal = function() {
        vm.isEditing = false;
        vm.addGameForm.$setPristine();
        vm.isSaving = true;
      }
      vm.addGame = function() {
        vm.isSaving = true;
        vm.newGame.id = vm.games.length + 1;
        // vm.newGame.gameDate = dateTransform(vm.newGame.gameDate);
        // get team name for notification
        vm.getTeamName = function(id) {
          return vm.teams[id-1].teamName
        }
        GameService.save(vm.newGame, function() {
          vm.addGameForm.$setPristine();


          // set var for overtime
          overtime = '';
          if(vm.newGame.hadOT == true){
            overtime = "(OT)";
          }
          if(vm.newGame.hadSO == true){
            overtime = "(SO)";
          }


          vm.games = GameService.query();
          vm.hideModal();
          ////////// CALL TO REFRESH /////////
          window.location.reload();
        })
      }
      var data = TournamentService.then(function(data) {
        vm.tournament = data.tournament
        vm.games = data.games;
        vm.hipchatroom = vm.tournament.hipchatroom;
        vm.hipchatkey = vm.tournament.hipchatkey;
        vm.teams = vm.tournament.teams
        vm.numberOfTeams = vm.teams.length;
        vm.totalGames = ((vm.numberOfTeams -1) * 2) * vm.numberOfTeams
        vm.percentGamesPlayed = (vm.games.length * 100) / vm.totalGames;
        vm.progressGrid = ProgressGrid.init(vm.numberOfTeams);
        Stats.calculateStandings(vm.games, vm.teams, vm.progressGrid);
      });

      vm.getTeamName = function(id) {
        return vm.teams[id-1].teamName
      }

    }])
    .factory('Stats', function() {
      var calc = {
        calculateStandings: function(games, teams, progressGrid) {
          var homeTeam, awayTeam, gameResult, winner, loser, ot, standings;
          _.each(games, function(game) {
            homeTeam = teams[game.homeTeam-1];
            awayTeam = teams[game.awayTeam-1];
            gameResult = {};
            winner = {};
            loser = {}
            ot = {};
            standings = [];

            ot.isOvertime = game.hadOT;
            ot.isShootout = game.hadSO;
            if( game.awayTeamScore > game.homeTeamScore ) {
              winner.team = awayTeam;
              winner.score = game.awayTeamScore;
              loser.team = homeTeam;
              loser.score = game.homeTeamScore;

            } else if ( game.awayTeamScore < game.homeTeamScore ) {
              winner.team = homeTeam;
              winner.score = game.homeTeamScore;
              loser.team = awayTeam;
              loser.score = game.awayTeamScore;
            }
            // adds game to grid
            calc.formattedResults(game, homeTeam.id,  awayTeam.id, progressGrid)
            // adds scores to team
            calc.recordGameResults(winner, loser, ot)
            // other stats
            angular.forEach(teams, function (team, index) {
              team.goalDifferential = team.goalsFor - team.goalsAgainst
              team.gamesPlayed = team.wins + team.regulationLosses + team.overtimeShootoutLosses
              team.regulationOvertimeWins = team.wins - team.shootoutWins
              team.points = team.wins * 2 + team.overtimeShootoutLosses * 1 + team.regulationLosses * 0
            });
          })
        },
        recordGameResults: function(winner, loser, ot) {
          if ( ot.isShootout || ot.isOvertime ) {
            loser.team.overtimeShootoutLosses++
          }
          else {
            loser.team.regulationLosses++
          }

          if ( ot.isShootout ) {
            winner.team.shootoutWins++
            loser.team.shootoutLosses++
          }
          winner.team.wins++
          winner.team.goalsFor += winner.score
          winner.team.goalsAgainst += loser.score

          loser.team.goalsFor += loser.score
          loser.team.goalsAgainst += winner.score
        },
        formattedResults: function(game, homeTeamID, awayTeamID, progressGrid) {
          var formattedResult = game.awayTeamScore + "-" + game.homeTeamScore + " ";
          formattedResult += game.hadSO ? '(SO)' : '' ||  game.hadOT ? '(OT)' : '';
          progressGrid[homeTeamID - 1][awayTeamID - 1] = formattedResult;
          return formattedResult

        }
      }
      return calc;
    })
    .factory('ProgressGrid', function() {
      var grid = {
        init: function(numberOfTeams) {
          var g = new Array(numberOfTeams)
          for(var i = 0; i < numberOfTeams; i++) {
            g[i] = new Array(numberOfTeams);
            for(var j = 0; j < numberOfTeams; j++) {
              g[i][j] = "";
            }
          }
          return g;
        }
      }
      return grid;
    });
}());
```

Tournament Service

```
(function(){
  angular.module('n16', ['ui.router', 'Dashboard', 'Games', 'Teams', 'Players'])

    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

      $stateProvider
        .state('dashboard', {
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: '/app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
          controller: 'dashboardController as ctrl'
        })
        .state('teams', {
          url: '/teams',
          templateUrl: '/app/teams/teams.html',
          controller: 'teamsController as ctrl'
        })
        .state('games', {
          url: '/games',
          templateUrl: '/app/games/games.html',
          controller: 'gamesController as ctrl'
        })
        .state('players', {
          url: '/players',
          templateUrl: '/app/players/players.html',
          controller: 'playersController as ctrl'
        });
    }])
    .controller('navigationController', function() {
      var self = this;
      self.navList = []
    })
    .service('TournamentService', ['$http','$q',function($http, $q) {
      var getTournament = function() {
        return $http.get('/tournaments/2016B', {cache: true }).then(function(tournament) {
          return tournament.data[0]
        })
      }
      var getGames = function() {
        return $http.get('/games').then(function(games) {
          return games.data
        })
      }

      return $q.all([getTournament(), getGames()]).then(function(resultsArray) {
        var tournament = resultsArray[0]
        var games = resultsArray[1]
        return {
          tournament: tournament,
          games: games,
          teams: tournament.teams
        }
      });
    }]);
})();
```

This is the view

```
<!-- Progress Grid -->
<h3 class="">Games Played: {{ ctrl.games.length }} of {{ctrl.totalGames}} <span class="text-muted">({{ ctrl.percentGamesPlayed | number : 0 }}%)</span></h3>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="team in ctrl.teams">
        {{team.teamName}}
      </th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="teamAway in ctrl.teams">
      <td ng-repeat="teamHome in ctrl.teams" ng-class="{bg: $index==$parent.$index}" width="177">
        {{ ctrl.progressGrid[teamAway.id - 1][teamHome.id - 1] }}
        <!-- <span class="text-danger">{{ teamAway.id - 1 }}, {{ teamHome.id - 1 }}</span> -->
      </td>
      <th>
        @{{teamAway.teamName}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- Team Standings -->
<h3>Standings</h3>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th>Team Name</th>
        <th>Players</th>
        <th>GP</th>
        <th>W</th>
        <th>RL</th>
        <th>OSL</th>
        <th>PTS</th>
        <th>SW</th>
        <th>SL</th>
        <th>ROW</th>
        <th>GF</th>
        <th>GA</th>
        <th>GDIFF</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="team in ctrl.teams | orderBy: ['-points', 'gamesPlayed', '-regulationOvertimeWins','-goalDifferential']">

        <td width="130">{{team.teamName}}</td>
        <td>{{team.player1}}<br>{{team.player2}}</td>
        <td class="statDetail">{{team.gamesPlayed}}</td>
        <td class="statDetail">{{team.wins}}</td>
        <td class="statDetail">{{team.regulationLosses}}</td>
        <td class="statDetail">{{team.overtimeShootoutLosses}}</td>
        <td class="statDetail">{{team.points}}</td>
        <td class="statDetail">{{team.shootoutWins}}</td>
        <td class="statDetail">{{team.shootoutLosses}}</td>
        <td class="statDetail">{{team.regulationOvertimeWins}}</td>
        <td class="statDetail">{{team.goalsFor}}</td>
        <td class="statDetail">{{team.goalsAgainst}}</td>
        <td class="statDetail">{{team.goalDifferential}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<hr>
<h1>
  Games
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-show="!ctrl.isEditing" ng-click="ctrl.showModal()">Add Game</button>
</h1>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <th>Game #</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Final Score</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr ng-repeat="game in ctrl.games | orderBy: '-id'">
        <td>{{ game.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ game.gameDate | date: medium }}</td>
        <td>
          <span ng-class="{ 'winner': game.awayTeamScore > game.homeTeamScore }">{{  ctrl.getTeamName(game.awayTeam) }}</span>
          @
          <span ng-class="{ 'winner': game.homeTeamScore > game.awayTeamScore }">{{ ctrl.getTeamName(game.homeTeam) }}</span>
          <span>{{ game.awayTeamScore }} - {{game.homeTeamScore }}</span>
          <span class="label label-warning" ng-show="game.hadOT && !game.hadSO">OT</span>
          <span class="label label-danger" ng-show="game.hadSO">SO</span>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-show="ctrl.games.length < 1 "><td colspan="3">no games played at this time.</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="modal show" ng-show="ctrl.isEditing">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <form  class="modal-content" name="ctrl.addGameForm" ng-submit="ctrl.addGame()">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Add Game</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="date">Game Date</label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" name="gameDate" ng-model="ctrl.newGame.gameDate" required>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-5 well">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Away Team</label>

                  <select name="awayTeam" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.newGame.awayTeam" required>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option ng-repeat="team in ctrl.teams" value="{{ team.id }}">{{ team.teamName }}</option>
                  </select>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Final Score</label>
                  <input type="number" name="awayTeamScore" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.newGame.awayTeamScore" required min="0"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
                @
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-5 well">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Home Team</label>
                  <select name="homeTeam" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.newGame.homeTeam" required>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option ng-repeat="team in ctrl.teams" value="{{ team.id }}">{{ team.teamName }}</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Final Score</label>
                  <input type="number" name="homeTeamScore" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.newGame.homeTeamScore" required min="0" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="hadOT" ng-model="ctrl.newGame.hadOT" ng-click="ctrl.newGame.hadSO = false">
                Overtime
              </label>
              <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="hadSO" ng-model="ctrl.newGame.hadSO" ng-click="ctrl.newGame.hadOT = false">
                Shoot Out
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="reset" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="ctrl.hideModal()">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="(ctrl.newGame.homeTeam === ctrl.newGame.awayTeam) || (ctrl.newGame.homeTeamScore === ctrl.newGame.awayTeamScore)  || ctrl.isSaving">Add Game</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You probably need to call again the tournament service becoase call a controller refresh its not enough ( $route.reload() doesn't refresh the services )

Comment: do you have a suggestion?

Comment: can you post your tournament service??

Comment: It's in that controller

Comment: no its not....i cant see where TournamentService.then(function(---> data <---) {  data came from.... but you can add a method to to tournament service and call that method when you need to refresh

Comment: Sorry my apology. I posted it now.

Comment: Sorry I just realized I had not added the file that contained the Tournament Service. Just posted the code. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your service is serving a dual purpose of being a model & an API service.  Because you are returning the result of those API calls, it's getting cached as the injected value for `TournamentService`.  I'd suggest you separate that logic.  Your service would better serve this purpose like so:

```
.service('TournamentService', ['$http','$q',function($http, $q) {
  api = {
     getTournament: function() {
        return $http.get('/tournaments/2016B', {cache: true })
            .then(function(tournament) { return tournament.data[0]})
     }
     getGames: function() {
         return $http.get('/games')
            .then(function(games){ return games.data })
     }
  }

  return api
```

Then in your controller you can call the service using the `$q.all` to aggregate/massage the data from the services.

```
.controller('DashboardContoller', function(... TournamentService){
    $q.all([TournamentService.getTournnament(), TournamentService.getGames()])
    .then(function(rsps){
        vm.tournament = rsps[0]; 
        vm.games = rsps[1];
        ...
     })
```

I tend to think of services in a very granular way so that you can have the controllers pick & choose the sequence of how they request their data.

Comment: jusopi, thanks for your suggestion. I'm getting this error  -> TournamentService.getTournnament is not a function

Comment: if you can throw it up on jsfiddle or plunker I might be able to trouble shoot it for you.  I usually code in Coffeescript so my raw JS might be a little off.

Comment: your fiddle is broken.  I don't think it's loading up angular or something.  If you get it running the templates should render correctly rather than all the {{ }} everywhere.

Comment: The problem is that the data is dynamic and comes from a mongodb collection. It would take me to long to reproduce all this with static info.

Comment: It's not even that, it was the fact that angular wasn't initializing properly (e.g. the binding was broken).  I tried 'fiddling' with it, no pun intended but couldn't get it up and running.  The data isn't the issue, we can mock fake data even in the most simple form in order to troubleshoot the error you were getting.

Comment: jusopi, Using your code snippets I managed to fix the function error. Now I want the view to update every time GameService.save is called in the dashboard controller. Do you have a suggestion for that?

Comment: Yes but it requires defining a pseudo-controller API that you can reuse elsewhere. Rather than using anonymous functions for *$q's* `then` & `catch` callbacks, you define things say like controller `getViewData` and `getViewData_success`.  Then in the constructor you can pass the response from your `$q.all` calls to the `getViewData_success`.  Likewise you can pass the response from your save call to the `getViewData_success` assuming that it returns the newly saved view data.  The comments don't really allow for answering this here.  You might ask another question and link to it?

Comment: btw, if the above answer indeed answers your original question and solves the original problem, please be sure to mark it as the answer.

Comment: I actually wrapped $q.all call into a functions and call that function from the GameService.save in the dashboard controller and it works. May not be the correct way of doing it but it gets the job done.